# Deserialization of TimeZoneInfo leads to exception in Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mono

I've serialized `TimeZoneInfos` to strings (around 115 items).
When I try to deserialize them in Xamarin Android application, I get an exception for some of them.

> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Serialization error.
>
> at System.TimeZoneInfo.DeserializeAdjustmentRule (System.Text.StringBuilder& input) [0x0000f] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3540/1cf254db/source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System/TimeZoneInfo.Serialization.cs:80
>
> at System.TimeZoneInfo.FromSerializedString (System.String source) [0x0003d] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3540/1cf254db/source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System/TimeZoneInfo.Serialization.cs:47
>
> at Core.Framework.Extension.Shared.Time.HardCodedTimeZonesProvider.DeserializeTimeZone (System.String x) [0x00002] in TimeZonesProvider.cs:29

An example of serialized time zone what can't be deserialized.

```
TimeZoneInfo.FromSerializedString("Venezuela Standard Time;-270;(UTC-04:30) Caracas;Venezuela Standard Time;Venezuela Daylight Time;[01:01:0001;12:31:2006;0;[1;00:00:00;1;1;];[1;00:00:00.001;1;1;];30;];");
```

I've figured out that the problem is with last number: **30**, so next line works fine:

```
TimeZoneInfo.FromSerializedString("Venezuela Standard Time;-270;(UTC-04:30) Caracas;Venezuela Standard Time;Venezuela Daylight Time;[01:01:0001;12:31:2006;0;[1;00:00:00;1;1;];[1;00:00:00.001;1;1;];];");
```

In desktop application deserialization works fine. So, Is it due to Mono or misconfiguration from my side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a look at sources and have noticed that implementations of `ToSerializedString` and `FromSerializedString` differ.

The last number: 30, is `BaseUtcOffsetDelta` for an `AdjustmentRule`. Mono implementation doesn't expect this parameter and throws the above-mentioned exception.

I've fixed that with binary serialization/deserialization.